# how do i remove uri path information?

Tags: java, android, file, uri

I have requirement like  i need to deleted selected file information if anybody selected wrong file, but after call delete() method its deleted from gallery also,
my question is how can remove selected file URI information i dont want to delete selected file form gallery, any help?

Comment: hi gyas, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Working with Android Architecture Components, such as: View Model, LiveData, etc. I would like to suggest you to follow [Official Guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) from Android.

When using Android Architecture Components to call a API request, how I try to achieve my goal is as follow:

- Create one Repo class, in that class, initialize the Retrofit Interface(if using Retrofit). Create a function that calls the required API, handle request response and returns a Live Data. Make extra functions for the parameter to be passed with URL.
- Create one View Model class, in that class, initialize above Repo class. Create a function that calls repo class function which returns Live Data and this function also returns LiveData. Make extra functions for the parameter to be passed to Repo for adding with URL.
- In your View class (Activity/Fragment), initialize View Model class and pass those parameters which are required URL params. Call the View Model function, which returns Live Data and observe that in your View class.

You will get data in your View Class when any change appears in Live Data.

Above is a simple practice, but it can be made good by making responses generic according to your requirement.

Comment: what do you mean by generic response? can you explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create public function in VM and pass desired paramas to it and then invoke desired URL from repo .

Refer example
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/viewmodel/ProductListViewModel.java

Comment: Any example, because when i try i'm able to get either value or api call but not both at a time.

Answer (score 0):

you can call some public method from viewmodel and then pass params to it.somehow like this

viewmodel

```
class UserViewmodel: ViewModel() {

    fun callApi(userId: String) : Any {
      // Your method definition



        return result
    }
}
```

and in activity / fragment call method via viewmodel instance

```
class UserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewmodel::class.java)
        val result = viewModel.callApi("userId")
    }
}
```

Comment: i want that value in same user view model and pass this user id parameter in some URL which is get method.

Comment: yes! you already get user id parameter in above `callApi(userId: String)` method of `UserViewmodel`